# quartz scheduling in spring 3 with batch file

Tags: spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

i have a batch(backup.bat)file.in that i have written a command to create a backup of database
which is

```
<
set path=%path%;C:\Program files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;
mysqldump -u `root` -padmin -B jewellery > backup\jewellery.sql
exit
>
```

i have created a controller to call this batch file.
that is given below

```
<
public class JobScheduleController extends QuartzJobBean {
      protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {
          // check FTP
          try {
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start Backup.bat");
.....
.....
......
catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                }
      }
}
>
```

even i have given the mapping in bean.xml that is given below

!-- Start Job Schedule for Application Backup Controllers-->

```
<bean name="jobScheduleController" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
  <property name="jobClass" value="com.jewellery.web.JobScheduleController" />
</bean>

<bean id="cronjobScheduleController" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobScheduleController" />
    <!-- run at 11 am (0  0  11  ?  *  *") (Seconds,Minutes,Hours,Day-of-Month,Month,Day-of-Week) -->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 11 ? * *" />
</bean>

<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronjobScheduleController" />
            </list> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

the problem is as per the given time the controller shuld search and invoke the batch file to execute.but it says the batch file not found.

where shuld i place the batch file .

the same code was running succussfully in spring 2.0,nw i have migrated to spring 3.
where shuld i place my batch file.?

i am using eclipse indigo...?and one more thing is this the best way to do it or some other way is also there..if there kindly let me knw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `Backup.bat` in your environment `path` variable

Comment: i have set the path brother...set path=%path%;C:\Program files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin; u telling me to put the loaction of backup.bat in enviroment right

Comment: No, first you need to set the path manually so that the BAT file will get resolved so add the bat file in the path first

Comment: bro,i hve set the path variable like this   %path%;C:\Program files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\Backup.bat;   is this right.

Comment: but before you load that bat file your OS should be able to find that. so before running the app you go in your environment setting and set the path by hand then run

Comment: i have done it.but its not working...i tried running the command manually in command promt...it tell The system cannot find the path specified.i am using windows 7,do u thing it might be a problem with that OS.

Comment: but little problem...when i run the project in Eclipse..it triggers and generates the backup....but when i created a .war file and try to run the application....it dint trigger the file nor created the backup.....

Comment: There should be some exception